# Unique "Value" Issue with MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I am having a small and annoying issue with my MySQL database.

I have a field `StudentID` that is supposed to be unique for each user but is not mandatory.

So when the user registers and doesn't want to add a `studentID` - he leaves the field blank. However when a 2nd user leaves the field blank - it counts it as a duplicate value.

Is there any way to fix this ?I tried several methods posted below :

> Mysql Error : 1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key
>   'users_studentid_unique'

1st time (works) :

```
insert into `users` (`username`, `name`, `email`, `studentid`, 
                     `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values ('aaaaaa263', 'aaaaaa', 'aaaaaa23d@gmail.com','' ,
        'yZPeKRV0C0xbr/QCI1w/Y.0Z1qSGnJeivgP71epaHpT139g65hAf2', 
        '2014-03-20 18:16:54', '2014-03-20 18:16:54')
```

2nd time (Duplicate value error for studentid) :

```
insert into `users` (`username`, `name`, `email`, `studentid`,
                     `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values ('aaaaaa263', 'aaaaaa', 'aaaaaa23d@gmail.com','' ,
        'yZPeKRV0C0xbr/QCI1w/Y.0Z1qSGnJeivgP71epaHpT139g65hAf2', 
        '2014-03-20 18:16:54', '2014-03-20 18:16:54')
```

Tried :

Checking the `NULL` value on the `studentid` table in the database.

Tried inserting into the db using these values instead of the blank field :

```
NULL
null
UNDEFINED
```

---

Still having the same issue though, - Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Multiple `NULL` values will not violate a `UNIQUE` constraint.  However, specifying a value of `NULL` on a `NOT NULL` column may fallback to its `DEFAULT` value: is your column nullable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `NULL` value, that's not considered to be a "duplicate" in a unique index. But the column has to allow NULL values, that is, it cannot be defined as `NOT NULL`.

To insert a `NULL` value, use the keyword `NULL` keyword. Note that this is different than the character string `'NULL'`

```
INSERT INTO mytab (a, b) VALUES (NULL, 'NULL')
```

Column a is assigned the special `NULL` value. Column b is assigned a character string.

Also, omitting the column from the INSERT list will cause the default value to be assigned to the column. The default value for a column is NULL, unless you've set the default to be something else.

This statement is equivalent to the statement above, in that column a will be assigned the default value defined for column a, which is

```
 INSERT INTO mytab (b) VALUES ('NULL')
```

The other option is to use an expression to generate the NULL value for you, in the place of the empty string.

Given a description of your current logic, if the user_id column allows for NULL values, then you could translate the empty string to NULL

```
insert into `users` (`username`, `name`, `email`, `studentid`,
                     `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values ( ?, ?, ?, NULLIF( ? ,''), ?, ?, ?)
```

The `NULLIF(x,y)` function is shorthand for `IF x = y THEN NULL ELSE x END`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the student id to a timestamp if it's null, then check if its numeric to see if it's really set or not.

```
<?php

$student_id = is_null($student_id) ? time() : $student_id;
```

Your request :

```
insert into `users` (`username`, `name`, `email`, `studentid`, 
                     `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values ('aaaaaa263', 'aaaaaa', 'aaaaaa23d@gmail.com','$student_id' ,
        'yZPeKRV0C0xbr/QCI1w/Y.0Z1qSGnJeivgP71epaHpT139g65hAf2', 
        '2014-03-20 18:16:54', '2014-03-20 18:16:54')
```

Then to get the users back :

```
SELECT *, if(concat('','student_id' * 1) = 'student_id', 0, 1) as is_student_id_valid from ...
```

Then `is_studient_id_valid` field will tell you if this id is valid or not.

Comment: I'm actualli inserting into the db with a php script and the studentID field is set as VARCHAR in the db.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to recreate your problem. Alas, it works fine here.

However, i supply all the information so that you can at least check where your setup is different.

Create table statement: Please check all of: the Mysql Version, the table engine, the primary key and the index on the 'studentid' column.

```
/*
SQLyog Community v10.2 
MySQL - 5.5.16 : Database - testmysql
*********************************************************************
*/

/*Table structure for table `users` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `username` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `studentid` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `studentid_uidx` (`studentid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Typical insert with a null studentid...

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `name`, `email`, `studentid`,
                     `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
VALUES ('aaaaaa004', 'aaaaaa', 'aaaaaa23d@gmail.com', NULL,
        'yZPeKRV0C0xbr/QCI1w/Y.0Z1qSGnJeivgP71epaHpT139g65hAf2', 
        '2014-03-20 18:16:54', '2014-03-20 18:16:54')
```

query result

```
username    name    email                studentid  password    created_at  updated_at
aaaaaa001   aaaaaa  aaaaaa23d@gmail.com (NULL)  yZPeKRV0C0xbr/QCI1w/Y.0Z1qSGnJeivgP71epaHpT139g65hAf2   2014-03-20 18:16:54 2014-03-20 18:16:54
aaaaaa002   aaaaaa  aaaaaa23d@gmail.com (NULL)  yZPeKRV0C0xbr/QCI1w/Y.0Z1qSGnJeivgP71epaHpT139g65hAf2   2014-03-20 18:16:54 2014-03-20 18:16:54
aaaaaa003   aaaaaa  aaaaaa23d@gmail.com stid01  yZPeKRV0C0xbr/QCI1w/Y.0Z1qSGnJeivgP71epaHpT139g65hAf2   2014-03-20 18:16:54 2014-03-20 18:16:54
aaaaaa004   aaaaaa  aaaaaa23d@gmail.com (NULL)  yZPeKRV0C0xbr/QCI1w/Y.0Z1qSGnJeivgP71epaHpT139g65hAf2   2014-03-20 18:16:54 2014-03-20 18:16:54
```